# Find total of each category if we know total of components used in those categories

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Lets say we have 3 products - *item1, item2, item3*
and these are made of substances *N, P, K* and something else.

The composition of these products be like:

```
item1 = 34% of N substance + 0% of P substance + 0% of K 
item2 = 10% of N + 34% of P + 0% of K
item3 = 11% of N + 37% of P + 5% of K
```

Note: remaining % are something else that we don't care.

Now what will be total value of item1, item2, item3 if we were to completely utilize total available   N, P, K substances

```
Total N substance available = 100
Total P substance available = 200
Total K substance available = 50
```

Comment: @whoisit fixed the type, its 5 for this example

Comment: I think some of the numbers are wrong in the question, I'll post an answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have $a, b, c$ units of item1, item2, item3 respectively.

Then, total `N` substance is : $0.34a+0.10b+0.11c$ 
To completely utilize, this must equal $100$. 
That is, $0.34a+0.10b+0.11c = 100$ 
Similarly, we get:  $0a+0.34b+0.37c=200$ and $0a+0b+0.05c = 50$

Thus we have 3 equations in 3 variables, which can be solved easily. 
If the final solution is $a\geq 0, b \geq 0, c\geq 0$ - then total utilization is possible; else at least for some substance, total utilization will not be possible.